# max in a list of tuples (Python)

Tags: python, list, tuples, max

I have this list of list of tuples

```
var1 = [
    [(10, '♣'), (7, '♠')],
    [(14, '♣'), (2, '♣')],
    [(2, '♥'), (9, '♦')],
    [(11, '♠'), (10, '♠')],
    [(11, '♦'), (5, '♣')]
]
```

and I wanna extract the tuple with the maximun value which is the second one or var1[1]. I've used a lot of different codes during my programming but the one I'm using now and until now and didn't have any major issues is this one:

```
 maximo = max(var1, key=lambda x: sum(i for i,_ in x))
```

also this one:

```
 maximo2 = list(map(max,zip(*var1)))
```

The problem is I need the list with the biggest value, not the one with the combinations of the 2 biggest, and right now this code is outputting `var1[3]` as the bigger of the 2 and I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `max` instead of `sum`

**Ex:**

```
var1=[[(10, '♣'), (7, '♠')], [(14, '♣'), (2, '♣')], [(2, '♥'), (9, '♦')], [(11, '♠'), (10, '♠')], [(11, '♦'), (5, '♣')]]
maximo=max(var1, key=lambda x: max(i for i,_ in x))
print(maximo)
```

**Output:**

```
[(14, '♣'), (2, '♣')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the built-in function `max` with parameter  `key`:

```
max(var1, key=max)
```

output:

```
[(14, '♣'), (2, '♣')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `max` and `operator.itemgetter` here as well:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> var1=[[(10, '♣'), (7, '♠')], [(14, '♣'), (2, '♣')], [(2, '♥'), (9, '♦')], [(11, '♠'), (10, '♠')], [(11, '♦'), (5, '♣')]]
>>> max(var1, key=itemgetter(0))
[(14, '♣'), (2, '♣')]
```